# How to filter gathering facts inside a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm working on a role that only needs to gather a single fact.

Performance it's a concern and I know that gathering facts it's time-consuming.

I'm looking for some way to filter `gather_facts` inside a playbook, this will allow me to gather only the required facts.

This is possible using the setup core module:

```
ansible -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_hostname' my_host

10.200.0.127 | success >> {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_hostname": "my_host"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

It's possible to use this feature inside the playbook? Something like this?

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: True
    filter: "filter=ansible_*"
```

***PS:*** The code above throws syntax exception.

**EDIT 1**: If someone needs to get hostname there's also another useful variable [inventory_hostname](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but not in the default behavior of gathering facts. Having set `gather_facts` to `true` simply calls the [setup module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) as very first task of the play. This way you do not have any way to parameterize the `setup` module call.

But you can disable the default behavior and call setup yourself with the filter parameter.

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
   - setup:
       filter: ansible_*
```

Since you're working on a role and might not want to have this setup call in your role, you could make use of pre_tasks.

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: False
  pre_tasks:
   - setup:
       filter: ansible_*
  roles:
   - your_role_here
```

Answer (score 22):

The Ansible way at the top of the playbook (Additional way):

```
----
- hosts: web
  gather_facts: True
  gather_subset:
    - network
    - virtual
```

Debug vars with:

```
  - name: Print some debug information 
    vars: 
      msg: |
          Module Variables ("vars"):
          --------------------------------
          {{ vars | to_nice_json }} 

          Environment Variables ("environment"):
          --------------------------------
          {{ environment | to_nice_json }} 

          GROUP NAMES Variables ("group_names"):
          --------------------------------
          {{ group_names | to_nice_json }}

          GROUPS Variables ("groups"):
          --------------------------------
          {{ groups | to_nice_json }}

          HOST Variables ("hostvars"):
          --------------------------------
          {{ hostvars | to_nice_json }} 

    debug: 
      msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"       
    tags: debug_info
```

Comment: I needed this way to update my existing playbooks with minimum changes. Using command similar to this to get all the possible subsets: ansible remote1 -i myhosts -m setup -a 'gather_subset='

Answer (score 15):

After this question was asked and answered, [Ansible 2.1 added the `gather_subset` option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html#options) to the setup module so its now possible to use the `!facter,!ohai,network` syntax described in the documentation rather than a regex filter:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: False
  pre_tasks:
   - setup:
       gather_subset: !facter,!ohai,network
  roles:
   - your_role_here
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you're interested in is the hostname of each host then simply doing something like this should do what you need:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Get hostname
      command: /bin/hostname
      register: my_hostname

    - debug: var=my_hostname
```

If it's some other fact that you're interested in then just specify the appropriate command, and refer to the fact via the registered variable.